# VueJS 3 composition API lifecycle not taking onMounted into account

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm creating a greeting card app with VueJS3. I want to download 2 images (the background and a star sprite), then showing the image with animated sprites.
If I put `onMounted"`at the end it doesn't work, I have this error:

```
[Vue warn]: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement. 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

If I put `onMounted` like this, it doesn't show the `MOUNTED` log...

```
<template>
  <div class="board">
    <canvas
      id='carte'
      ref='carte'
      :width="size.w"
      :height="size.h"
      max-width="100%"
      tabindex='0'
      style="border:1px solid #000000;"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="texteRemplacement" v-if="petit">
    <p v-for="p in texte.split('\n')" v-bind:key="p">
      {{ p }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  defineComponent,
  onMounted,
  ref,
  reactive,
  nextTick,
  toRefs,
  watch,
} from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Visionneuse',
  props: ['texteEnvoye', 'taille'],
  async setup(props) {
    const myCanvas = ref(null);
    const carte = ref(null);
    const { texteEnvoye, taille } = toRefs(props);
    const texte = ref('');
    const rapport = ref(0);
    const petit = ref((window.innerWidth < 750));
    const size = reactive({
      w: window.innerWidth * taille.value,
      h: window.innerHeight * taille.value,
    });
    const tailleFond = reactive({
      w: 0,
      h: 0,
    });
    let fpsInterval;
    let startTime;
    let now;
    let then;
    let elapsed;

    function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }

    function genererEtoile() {
      return ({
        taille: getRandomInt(10) + 10,
        position: {
          x: Math.random(),
          y: Math.random(),
        },
        deviation: {
          x: {
            valeur: getRandomInt(18) - 9,
            sens: 1,
            amplitude: 5 + getRandomInt(5),
          },
          y: {
            valeur: getRandomInt(8) - 4,
            sens: 1,
            amplitude: 5 + getRandomInt(5),
          },
        },
        grossissement: {
          valeur: getRandomInt(5) - 3,
          sens: 1,
        },
      });
    }

    const etoiles = ref(new Array(50).fill(null).map(() => (genererEtoile())));
    const date = ref([
      {
        valeur: {
          chiffre: '2',
          position: 0,
          sens: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        valeur: {
          chiffre: '0',
          position: 3,
          sens: -1,
        },
      },
      {
        valeur: {
          chiffre: '2',
          position: -3,
          sens: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        valeur: {
          chiffre: '1',
          position: -3,
          sens: -1,
        },
      },
    ]);

    function drawText() {
      const fontSize = 0.05 * size.w - 10;
      myCanvas.value.font = `${fontSize}px Caviar Dream`;
      myCanvas.value.textAlign = 'center';
      myCanvas.value.fillStyle = 'white';
      myCanvas.value.strokeStyle = 'black';
      myCanvas.value.lineWidth = 0.006 * size.w - 10;
      const x = (size.w * 9) / 13;
      const y = (size.h * 5) / 7;
      const lineHeight = fontSize;
      const lines = texte.value.split('\n');
      for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 1) {
        myCanvas.value.fillText(
          lines[lines.length - i - 1],
          x,
          y + ((lines.length - 1) * lineHeight) / 2 - (i * lineHeight),
        );
        // myCanvas.value.strokeText(
        //   lines[lines.length - i - 1],
        //   x,
        //   y + ((lines.length - 1) * lineHeight) / 2 - (i * lineHeight),
        // );
      }
    }

    watch(texteEnvoye, (x) => {
      texte.value = x;
      // requestAnimationFrame(initCarte);
    });

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('MOUNTED');
      const c = carte.value;
      const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
      myCanvas.value = ctx;
      // requestAnimationFrame(initCarte);
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      startAnimating(20);
    });

    async function getImage(chemin) {
      await axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLICPATH}img/${chemin}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(`data:${res.headers['content-type']};base64,${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(res.data)))}`);
          return `data:${res.headers['content-type']};base64,${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(res.data)))}`;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    const imgFond = await getImage('fond.jpeg');
    const imgEtoile = await getImage('etoile.png');

    function initCarte() {
      console.log('init de la carte');
      // changer les chargement
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

      requestAnimationFrame(initCarte);
      now = Date.now();
      elapsed = now - then;

      if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
        then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
        petit.value = window.innerWidth < 750;
        const etoile = new Image();
        // etoile.src = `${process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLICPATH}img/etoile.png`;
        etoile.src = imgEtoile;
        const background = new Image();
        // background.src = `${process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLICPATH}img/fond.jpeg`;
        background.src = imgFond;
        background.onload = () => {
          rapport.value = background.naturalWidth / background.naturalHeight;
          tailleFond.w = background.naturalWidth;
          tailleFond.h = background.naturalHeight;
          size.w = window.innerWidth * taille.value;
          size.h = size.w / rapport.value;
          if (size.w > window.innerWidth) {
            size.h = size.w / rapport.value;
          } else if (size.h > window.innerHeight) {
            size.h = window.innerHeight * taille.value;
            size.w = size.h * rapport.value;
          }
          nextTick(() => {
            try {
              myCanvas.value.drawImage(background, 0, 0, size.w, size.h);
              // on dessine les étoiles
              etoiles.value.forEach((e) => {
                if (e.grossissement.valeur > 2 && e.grossissement.sens === 1) {
                  e.grossissement.sens = -1;
                }
                if (e.grossissement.valeur < -3 && e.grossissement.sens === -1) {
                  e.grossissement.sens = 1;
                }
                if (e.deviation.x.valeur > e.deviation.x.amplitude && e.deviation.x.sens === 1) {
                  e.deviation.x.sens = -1;
                }
                if (e.deviation.x.valeur < -e.deviation.x.amplitude && e.deviation.x.sens === -1) {
                  e.deviation.x.sens = 1;
                }
                if (e.deviation.y.valeur > e.deviation.y.amplitude && e.deviation.y.sens === 1) {
                  e.deviation.y.sens = -1;
                }
                if (e.deviation.y.valeur < -e.deviation.y.amplitude && e.deviation.y.sens === -1) {
                  e.deviation.y.sens = 1;
                }
                e.deviation.x.valeur += e.deviation.x.sens;
                e.deviation.y.valeur += e.deviation.y.sens;
                e.grossissement.valeur += e.grossissement.sens;
                myCanvas.value.drawImage(etoile,
                  (e.position.x * size.w) + e.deviation.x.valeur - e.grossissement.valeur / 2,
                  (e.position.y * size.h) + e.deviation.y.valeur - e.grossissement.valeur / 2,
                  (e.taille + e.grossissement.valeur) * (size.w / background.naturalWidth),
                  (e.taille + e.grossissement.valeur) * (size.h / background.naturalHeight));
              });
              // on dessine 2021
              const fontSize = 0.1 * size.w - 10;
              myCanvas.value.font = `${fontSize}px Caviar Dream`;
              myCanvas.value.textAlign = 'center';
              myCanvas.value.fillStyle = 'white';
              myCanvas.value.strokeStyle = 'black';
              myCanvas.value.lineWidth = 0.006 * size.w - 10;
              const x = (size.w * 7) / 12;
              const y = (size.h * 4) / 9;
              const ecart = 0.07 * size.w - 10;
              date.value.forEach((ch, i) => {
                if (ch.valeur.position > 6 && ch.valeur.sens === 1) {
                  ch.valeur.sens = -1;
                }
                if (ch.valeur.position < -6 && ch.valeur.sens === -1) {
                  ch.valeur.sens = 1;
                }
                ch.valeur.position += 1 * ch.valeur.sens;
                myCanvas.value.fillText(
                  ch.valeur.chiffre,
                  x + (ecart * i),
                  y + ch.valeur.position,
                );
              });
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(`ERREUR DE CHARGEMENT D'IMAGE: ${e}`);
            }
            if (!petit.value) {
              drawText();
            }
          });
        };
      }
    }

    function startAnimating(fps) {
      fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;
      then = Date.now();
      startTime = then;
      console.log(startTime);
      initCarte();
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', initCarte);

    return {
      myCanvas,
      size,
      texte,
      petit,
      carte,
      tailleFond,
    };
  },
});

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Caviar Dream';
  src: local('Caviar Dream'), url(~@/assets/fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf) format('truetype');
}

#texteRemplacement {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: 'Caviar Dream';
}

#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

</style>
```

What did I not understand in [this page](https://learnvue.co/2020/12/how-to-use-lifecycle-hooks-in-vue3/)?

Comment: Asynchronous component is supposed to be used with Suspense only.

Comment: How could I wait for the images to be fetched, then?

Comment: The way you did it. You didn't show how you use the component. You should use this component with `<suspense>`.  It won't work without it, which is likely the reason why mount hook doesn't work